# View traffic of integrated WebLogic server in Jdeveloper

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

is there any way to monitor the traffic of the integrated WebLogic server in Jdeveloper. I know that must be at least possible via a network sniffer, though I haven't succeed that way ether. But isn't there a way via the IDE?

Thank you very much in advance,
Angelo Hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo that shows you how to setup the HTTP Analyzer in JDeveloper to monitor your HTTP traffic between the client and WebLogic:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/monitoring_adf_pages_round_trips

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Http Analyzer. Then on your browser, you need to setup the Proxy Server to that of the Http Analyzer. To see the port, go to Tools->Preferences->Http Analyser.

If you just want to see the HTTP requests and responses, it might be easier to just use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools.

A more detailed and illustrated instruction can be found here: http://nickaiva.blogspot.com/2010/10/jdeveloper-11g-making-use-of-http.html

Comment: http Analyser only shows requests done within the IDE. Isn't so?

Comment: In my setup it is like MaVRoSCy said. It only shows the requests done within the IDE

Comment: @Hyangelo My integrated weblogic listens on http://localhost:7101 . Can you please give us some hints about the configuration in the HTTP Analyzer on how to achieve this functionality? I tried to change the Listen On Port value to 7101 but still i don't get any thing from my Analyzer. Thanks

Comment: You have to set your browser's proxy to the Http Analyzer's port. The Http analyzer works as a 'proxy' so it could inspect connections.